# Get Google+ account name while inheriting from BaseGameActivity

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

My main activity extends the BaseGameActivity and I'm trying to get the username that is shown in the leaderboard. I tried using:

```
Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(getApiClient());
```

But it's not working, I'm getting:

```
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361): java.lang.NullPointerException: Appropriate Api was not requested.
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.hn.b(Unknown Source)
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.a(Unknown Source)
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.kj.a(Unknown Source)
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.kj.getAccountName(Unknown Source)
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361):    at com.gfel.maze.StartPage$4.onClick(StartPage.java:158)
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
07-26 15:03:44.624: E/AndroidRuntime(28361):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I know there is a way using GoogleApiClient.Builder but Im looking for another way since
I use BaseGameActivity.

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate method add 
setRequestedClients(BaseGameActivity.CLIENT_GAMES | BaseGameActivity.CLIENT_PLUS);

before super.conCreate(savedInstanceState)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // set requested clients (games and cloud save)
    setRequestedClients(BaseGameActivity.CLIENT_GAMES |
            BaseGameActivity.CLIENT_PLUS);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_leaderboard);
}
```

More info can be read at https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init